# syntax error when attempting to insert data into postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

I am attempting to insert parsed dta data into a postgresql database with each row being a separate variable table, and it was working until I added in the second row "recodeid_fk". The error I now get when attempting to run this code is: **pg8000.errors.ProgrammingError: ('ERROR', '42601', 'syntax error at or near "imp"')**.

Eventually, I want to be able to parse multiple files at the same time and insert the data into the database, but if anyone could help me understand whats going on now it would be fantastic. I am using Python 2.7.5, the statareader is from pandas 0.12 development records, and I have very little experience in Python.

```
dr = statareader.read_stata('file.dta')
a = 2
t = 1
for t in range(1,10):
    z = str(t)
    for date, row in dr.iterrows():
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO tblv00{} (data, recodeid_fk) VALUES({}, {})".format(z, str(row[a]),29))
    a += 1
    t += 1
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: **NEVER interpolate values directly into SQL like this**, you leave yourself critically vulnerable to [SQL injection](bobby-tables.com). Also, in future please mention your PostgreSQL version in questions. Thanks!

Comment: Also, whenever you see yourself doing something with SQL in a loop, think "how can I turn this into a set operation". In this case I'd suggest using the `COPY` command via Psycopg2's `COPY` support to bulk-insert the rows in one go from a generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To your specific error...**

The syntax error probably comes from strings `{}` that need quotes around them. `execute()` can take care of this for you automtically. Replace

```
execute("INSERT INTO tblv00{} (data, recodeid_fk) VALUES({}, {})".format(z, str(row[a]),29))

execute("INSERT INTO tblv00{} (data, recodeid_fk) VALUES(%s, %s)".format(z), (row[a],29))
```

The table name is completed the same way as before, but the the values will be filled in by `execute`, which inserts quotes if they are needed. Maybe `execute` could fill in the table name too, and we could drop `format` entirely, but that would be an unusual usage, and I'm guessing `execute` might (wrongly) put quotes in the middle of the name.

**But there's a nicer approach...**

Pandas includes [a function for writing DataFrames to SQL tables](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.sql.write_frame.html). Postgresql is not yet supported, but in simple cases you should be able to pretend that you are connected to sqlite or MySQL database and have no trouble.

What do you intend with `z` here? As it is, you loop z from `'1'` to `'9'` before proceeding to the next for loop. Should the loops be nested? That is, did you mean to insert the contents `dr` into nine different tables called `tblv001` through `tblv009`?

If you mean that loop to put different parts of `dr` into different tables, please check the indentation of your code and clarify it.

In either case, the link above should take care of the SQL insertion.

**Response to Edit**

It seems like `t`, `z`, and `a` are doing redundant things. How about:

```
import pandas as pd
import string

...

# Loop through columns of dr, and count them as we go.
for i, col in enumerate(dr):
    table_name = 'tblv' + string.zfill(i, 3) # e.g., tblv001 or tblv010
    df1 = DataFrame(dr[col]).reset_index()
    df1.columns = ['data', 'recodeid_fk']
    pd.io.sql.write_frame(df1, table_name, conn)
```

I used `reset_index` to make the index into a column. The new (sequential) index will not be saved by `write_frame`.

Comment: just edited my code in order to clarify your question. I do intend to loop different parts of dr into the separate tables